# Change from Dynamic Scoping to Static Scoping / Lexical Scoping

Tags: haskell, dynamic, static, scoping, lexical

How do I change `big_step_Decls (Proc p s)` to follow static scope rule and matching the proc type?

This is the rule for static proc declaration I want to implement:

```
<decls, env [p -> (s, env)] --> <sto', env'>
------------------------------------------------
<proc p is s : decls, env, sto > --> <sto', env'>
```

This is a snippet of the Haskell code for big step semantics for variable & procedural declarations.

```
data Env = Env {var :: Map String Loc, proc :: Map String (Stm, Env)} deriving Show

env0 = Env { var = empty, proc = empty}


big_step_Decls :: ([Decl], Env, Sto) -> (Env, Sto)

big_step_Decls ([], env, sto) = (env, sto)

big_step_Decls ((VarD x a): more_decls, env, sto) = (env', sto')
   where v = big_step_a env sto a'
         (l, sto'') = alloc sto
         env'' = env {var = insert x l (var env)}
         (env', sto') = big_step_Decls (more_decls, env'', insert l v sto'')

big_step_Decls ((Proc p s): more_decls, env, sto) = (env',sto')
   where env''  = env {proc = insert p s (proc env)}
         (env', sto') = big_step_Decls (more_decls, env'', sto)
```

This is the error I'm getting 
(PS: I'm new to Haskell and still trying to figure the basics out.)

```
BIPs.hs:161:31: error:
    * Couldn't match type `Stm' with `(Stm, Env)'
      Expected type: Map String (Stm, Env)
        Actual type: Map String Stm
    * In the `proc' field of a record
      In the expression: env {proc = (insert p s) (proc env)}
      In an equation for env'':
          env'' = env {proc = (insert p s) (proc env)}
    |
161 |    where env''  = env {proc = (insert p s) (proc env)}
    |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

BIPs.hs:161:45: error:
    * Couldn't match type `(Stm, Env)' with `Stm'
      Expected type: Map String Stm
        Actual type: Map String (Stm, Env)
    * In the third argument of `insert', namely `(proc env)'
      In the `proc' field of a record
      In the expression: env {proc = (insert p s) (proc env)}
    |
161 |    where env''  = env {proc = (insert p s) (proc env)}
    |                                             ^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't included the data definition for the `Decl` type. Could you make sure all the datatypes used in the question are included? Additionally, as this is not a field I'm familiar with, I can't tell if the "rule for the static proc declaration" you've given is sufficient for someone to know what it is you're attempting to implement, but it may help to provide a little more context to the question.

Answer (score 3):

In this expression `env''  = env {proc = (insert p s) (proc env)}` `p` is the map key and `s` the value. The values in the `proc` map have type `(Stm, Env)` but you are currently trying to insert `s` of type `Stm` only.

So you need to pass an additional environment to make your code compile. Something like:

```
env'' = env {proc = insert p (s, env) (proc env)}
```

I don't know if that makes sense in your program though :-).